# Hang using INSERT in cx_Oracle with Python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm using python 3.8.10 and cx_oracle 8.0.1 on windows 7

when connecting to the database, I can run "select" normally

but when trying to execute any "insert" python is processing infinitely. There is no error, it just gets stuck processing

How to solve this?

I'm using the following connection code:

```
def connect(self):
    self.conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=self.usuario_bd, password=self.password, dsn=self.str_conn, encoding="UTF-8")
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
```

and this code to insert:

```
def insert_ControleExecucao(self, xvar):
        self.connect()
        query = """INSERT INTO table (DT_var1, CD_var1, DT_var2, CD_var2, CD_var3, CD_var4, DT_var3)
            values (sysdate,:1, sysdate,:2,:3,:4,sysdate)"""
        self.cursor.execute(query,([self.usuario_os,self.usuario_os,self.cd_var11,xvar]))
        self.conn.commit()
```

but it stops before reaching the "commit" line

Comment: Does your table have a unique constraint/index, and do you have any uncommitted changes against the table in another session - e.g. in SQL\*Plus or Toad or whatever you use?

Comment: Thanks for answering! No, no unique constraint/index or uncommitted changes

Comment: See `gv$locked_object` to identify sessions that tries to modify this object